# How can I SUM rows that have at least X Boolean 1s?

Tags: sql, sum, boolean

Example table:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
Abe  1    0    1
Bob  0    1    0
Cam  1    1    1
Dan  1    0    0
Eve  1    1    1
```

How can I query so that I can `SUM` how many people in `col1` have a total of 2 1s? (So, since Abe is the only person with 2 1s, the query outputs the number 1.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select count(*) from table_name where col2+col3+col4=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use addition of columns in where clause and select count()

```
 select count(*)
 from my_table 
 where CAST(ifnull(col2,false) AS SIGNED INTEGER) + 
       CAST(ifnull(col3,false) AS SIGNED INTEGER) +
       CAST(ifnull(col4,false) AS SIGNED INTEGER)  = 2;
```

Comment: only thing.  If all columns are datatype bit will need to cast at least 1.  Also, if a null exists in one of the columns that entire addition operation becomes null (aka unknown)

Comment: @Matt  . i have update the answer with explict conversion for your comment

Comment: Looks good.  I know in sql-server because of how data is coalesced automatically I only had to cast 1 column but looks good for mysql and some of the others. I posted a sql-server answer so looks like we got it covered :)

Comment: your welcome I upvoted yours too I saw you where the first correct answer just thought I would help alleviate a couple of specific pitfalls I have seen in the past in my own adding of bit values, but you had it right

Answer (score 2):

If Your columns value contains only `0` and `1` then `Vlad Călin Buzea` and `scaisEdge` answer will work for you. But if it can have other than `0` and `1`, You need this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE (CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      (CASE WHEN col3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      (CASE WHEN col4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
```

Comment: using 0 in your else statements would be more standard especially if someone wanted to expand their criteria to say more than 1 > 1

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'Abe' AS Col1, CAST(1 AS BIT) as Col2, CAST(0 AS BIT) as Col3, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS Col4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob' AS Col1, CAST(0 AS BIT) as Col2, CAST(1 AS BIT) as Col3, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS Col4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Cam' AS Col1, CAST(1 AS BIT) as Col2, CAST(1 AS BIT) as Col3, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS Col4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AbeWNull' AS Col1, CAST(1 AS BIT) as Col2, CAST(NULL AS BIT) as Col3, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS Col4
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    ISNULL(CAST(Col2 AS INT),0) + ISNULL(Col3,0) + ISNULL(Col4,0) = 2
```

The `cte` gives you some test data.  2 things.  1 if it is a `Boolean` or `bit` column you could have to `cast/convert` to an `integer` or `numeric` datatype at least one of the columns or the addition wont work. And yes I tested and needed to.  Second, if you don't deal with the potential of a `null` you may not get the answer you want.

For example.

```
SELECT 1 + NULL + 1
```

Will give you `NULL`

Using `SUM` on a column isn't the same and it will just ignore the `nulls`, but not during the addition line.